# Associating rows in a repeater with rows in a SQL database

Tags: sql, vb.net, repeater

I have the following repeater that gets filled by the data from a SQL database with let say four columns. Three of them shown in the repeater (Name, Min, Max) and the fourth one being the primary key in the table. If need be I can add the primary key field as an invisible label in the repeater.

```
<asp:repeater id="rpt" runat="server"> 
    <ItemTemplate>                                                   
        <asp:Label ID="repeaterLbl"  text = <%#Container.DataItem("Name")%>  runat="server"/>
        <asp:Textbox ID="repeaterMinNumber"  text = <%#Container.DataItem("Min")%> runat="server"/> 
        <asp:Textbox ID="repeaterMaxNumber" text = <%#Container.DataItem("Max")%>  runat="server"/>  <br />                            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

My question is if I change the text boxes text field (for Min or Max) and wish to save the data back into the SQL table, how can I associate the correct row in the repeater with the correct primary key (or row in the SQL table)? If providing code in code-behind please do so in Visual Basic.

Comment: Does the name uniquely define what is being stored so that it can become the primary key in the database? If not how does the user see which of two entries with the same name she is altering?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. However the answer below is exactly what I was looking for, whether or not "Name" is unique wasn't the issue.

Comment: if name is unique you don't require the hidden field - makes things much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen hidden fields used for the purpose you describe here.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="repeaterKey" runat="server" 
                 Value='<%#Container.DataItem("KeyField")%>' />
```

You can then refer to the hidden field as you would other fields (via id) but not have to worry about revealing the key to the client, end user, etc.

As for accessing the correct key to relate each item in the repeated fields.  I typically see our web developers using .FindControl like this:

```
    For nRow = 0 To rpt.Items.Count - 1

        Dim MyKey As New HiddenField

        MyKey = rpt.Items(nRow).FindControl("repeaterKey")

        Response.Write(MyKey.Value)  // Or do somthing useful with MyKey

    Next
```

Or by discovering values via the repeaters OnCommand event through use of the key field value being passed via the [CommandName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname) or [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) properties of buttons, or other controls.  Check microsoft docs for more info on how to do that.